# how to subnet a network or build a network with specific IP ranges

Tags: networking, routes, subnet, private-subnet, sub-network-access-protocol

let's say:- considering I am working in a company
 with 12 departments every department have between 7-10 PC's
and every department have 2-5 printers  so I need to divide/subnetting my network in order to make a range of IP addresses for every department PC's & printers  and start to set a static IP address for every pc / printer
how I can do that ??

what I need is: a guideline to how to build such a network
or what to learn to be able to do such a thing, keywords to search, types of a calculator to make such a thing

Notice: I watched a lot of courses & videos but all in cisco packet tracer I need to know how to do it in real life

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains all about IPv4 addressing and subnetting. There is a specific section on subnetting for departments based on the number of hosts in each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you need 12 x /28 subnet and 12 x /29

```
for example:
192.160.0.0 /28 pcs locaacion 1
192.168.0.16 /28 pcs location 2
192.168.0.32 /28 pcs location 3
.
.
192.168.0.192 /28 pcs location 13

so, you have 13 availabe addresses on each site for your pcs and 1 address for your default gateway (router), each subnet with a mask of 255.255.255.240

now do the same for your printers, but with a /29 subnet mask:

192.168.1.0 /29 printer loc 1
192.168.1.8 /29 printer loc 2
192.168.1.16 /29 printer loc 3
.
.
192.168.1.96 /29 printer loc 13

each subnet has space for 5 printer plus 1 address for the router. subnetmask would be 255.255.255.248
```

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwi_z6TcxuXlAhXxx6YKHXs6C20QFjAAegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cisco.com%2Fc%2Fen%2Fus%2Fsupport%2Fdocs%2Fip%2Frouting-information-protocol-rip%2F13788-3.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1yWOeJIvOH0nY7UyR-Oe8j

to optimize routing, you can allocate 2x/28 to your location, then you have:
192.168.0.0/28 & 192.168.0.16/28, one for printer and one for pc in location1.. so you have a /27 (255.255.255.224) on each site. means, only 1 routing entry in the network to reach site printer&pc

as you can see, it seems complicated if you have no clue about subnetting. read the above link carefully to undersrand ip addressing!